# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE TICKET
(
    TicketID int primary key,
    StartLoc varchar(20),
    FinalLoc varchar(20),
    price int,
    DateOfPurchase date,
    SeatNumber int,
    TrainID int,
    DepartureDate date ,
);

insert into TICKET
values (1,'HaydarPasa','Sirkeci',20,'20,18-06-12 10:34:09 AM',10,1,'20-06-12 10:34:09 AM')
```

I'm using SQL Server Management 2008 R2 version.When execute the query it says

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string SQL

Comment: You are missing 2 quotes here `'20,18-06-12 10:34:09 AM'` (after `20` and before `18`)

Comment: May be date format is wrong. BTW should not those date field be date time instead of date since you are inserting time too??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@juergenD is right, the string `20,18-06-12 10:34:09 AM` is not a date string. Is the `20` part of the insert? if so your table definition is off. I expect a copy-paste error here...

Additionally: When i try your query on my machine, it still gives an error converting to date. If I change the dates to the format `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss AM` it does work. Might be to do with local settings though.

Comment: Thanks this solved my problem..insert into TICKET
values (1,'HaydarPasa','Sirkeci',20,'2012-06-20',10,1,'2012-06-20 10:34:09')